# In Ember.js, how can I return a hard 404 code if a route is not found?

Tags: ember.js

[image: badurl]

I have the following route whenever a bad route is given from my webpage. The problem however, is that even though "technically" it says a 404, it's really not a 404. At the network level, this is actually a 200 level code.

[image: twohundredcode]

Now this makes sense. After all, the web server appropriately handles the URL but it's my ember app that catches the error.

Can I need explicitly send out a 404 using Ember.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the server doesn’t respond, you can’t “send” any response.

If you’re using fast-boot, you can sent a server response.

The bigger question is why does client app need a specific error code?

Most humans don’t care about an http status code (source: my grandma). However, handling missing models (server errors) and missing routes (wildcard routes in your router.js file), should handle most user-facing issues just fine.

Comment: That is not true. SEO engines will index the page if it return 200. Most websites made with Ember will produce 404 status code within error page. Audition tools will complain about error page returning 200 too.
https://www.wappalyzer.com/technologies/ember-js